# Fortify SCA integeration with IBM build tools

Tags: websphere, clearcase, fortify

I was wondering how to integrate Fortify with IBM WebSphere Rational Application Manager or Clearcase ?
I didn't find a plugin for it like Jenkins; I was wondering if it can be done in some other way, like a web-service integration.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for IBM's Urbancode Build (formerly AntHillPro). 
https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/fortify-360/

For automating the deployment to WebSphere App Server, you need to either write Jython scripts to deploy it, or use an automation tool like urbancode deploy.

Bottom line: you need a build server to integrate all of this.

Oh, and if you're still on ClearCase, I'd recommend moving to Rational Team Concert. Easier to manage, and it includes a build server, and scrum based project management tooling.